# Setting up android emulator for nativescript-vue

Tags: javascript, java, android, nativescript

I want to start playing with nativescript-vue, I installed nativescript and all needed dependencies, right now I'm setting up an android emulator using avdmanager, after downloading the package aimage I ran this command:

```
avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86
```

Now the installer is asking me all this questions I don't have any idea what they do and because of that I just hit enter fr next question, is this going to end with a messed up installation ? ... , I'm on my local windows dev machine.

It keeps goig and going, is there a way to have a predefined installation so I can skip the garillion of questions?

```
C:\Users\gabo_>sdkmanager --channel=3 emulator
[=======================================] 100% Unzipping... emulator/NOTICE.txt
C:\Users\gabo_>avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86"
Auto-selecting single ABI x86===========] 100% Fetch remote repository...
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile? [no] yes

PlayStore: Does the device supports Google Play?
PlayStore.enabled [no]:yes

avd home that was used during the construction of this hardware.ini: This can be used by post processing tools to migrate snapshots
android.avd.home []:

sdk root that was used during the construction of this hardware.ini: This can be used by post processing tools to migrate snapshots
android.sdk.root []:

ID of the AVD being run:
avd.id [<build>]:

Name of the AVD being run:
avd.name [<build>]:test

Cache partition support: Whether we use a /cache partition on the device.
disk.cachePartition [yes]:yes

Cache partition: Cache partition to use on the device. Ignored if disk.cachePartition is not 'yes'.
disk.cachePartition.path []:no

Cache partition size:
disk.cachePartition.size [66MB]:

Initial data partition: If not empty, its content will be copied to the disk.dataPartition.path file at boot-time.
disk.dataPartition.initPath []:

Path to data partition file: Path to data partition file. Cannot be empty. Special value <temp> means using a temporary file. If disk.dataPartition.initPath is not empty, its content will be copied to the disk.dataPartition.path file at boot-time.
disk.dataPartition.path [<temp>]:

Ideal size of data partition:
disk.dataPartition.size [0]:

Path to encryption key partition file: Path to encryption key partition file. Should be at least 16K bytes empty disk without any filesystem on it.
disk.encryptionKeyPartition.path []:

Path to the ramdisk image: Path to the ramdisk image.
disk.ramdisk.path []:

Path to snapshot storage: Path to a 'snapshot storage' file, where all snapshots are stored.
disk.snapStorage.path []:

Initial system partition image:
disk.systemPartition.initPath []:

Path to runtime system partition image:
disk.systemPartition.path []:

Ideal size of system partition:
disk.systemPartition.size [0]:

Initial vendor partition image:
disk.vendorPartition.initPath []:

Path to runtime vendor partition image:
disk.vendorPartition.path []:

Ideal size of vendor partition:
disk.vendorPartition.size [0]:

Always use cold boot: If set, AVD will always use the full cold boot instead of snapshot-based quick boot process
fastboot.forceColdBoot [no]:
```

And it kepps ging and going ...

Comment: Try using AVD Manager GUI comes with Android Studio to manage your Emulators easily.

Comment: Agreed. Install Android Studio. Little more to install, but the convenience of its tools over the command line is really good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to have a predefined installation by selecting [no] as answer to:

"Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile? [no]"

I struggled with this and found that it's easier to just select the default and move on.